# Oracle archive log file size

Tags: oracle10g

I have written a procedure which will get data from some tables and update a master table. each table contains records in the range 50k - 100k. when ever i execute this procedure, the archive log files is getting generated and the size of those log files is too much for my disk to handle.. it is generating more than 30GB of log files for each execution. 
What are the possible ways to handle this.